# MySQL query to delete 200,000 spam members located in three tables in ExpressionEngine

Tags: mysql, expressionengine

I've got a spam member problem with one of my ExpressionEngine sites. I've walked through the member group affected and written down the the member_id number for each member I want SAVE. I'm hoping to delete every other member from within the same group_id. The member data is stored in 3 different tables. Here's an equation I'm looking for, but in MySQL query language:

```
FROM tables = exp_member_data, exp_member_homepage, exp_members<br>
IF group_id = 5<br>
AND NOT member_id = 5, 6, 10, 107, 267, etc... <br>
DELETE remaining rows
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

---

***EDIT**

Thanks @Romil

Here's the end result that worked, as group_id wasn't in two tables:

```
DELETE FROM `exp_member_homepage`, `exp_member_data`
WHERE member_id not in ( 5, 10, 11, 15 )

***** be sure to add members from ALL member groups
```

AND

```
DELETE FROM `exp_members`
WHERE group_id = 5
AND member_id not in ( 5, 10, 11, 15 )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Delete from mytable where  group_id = 5
AND member_id not in ( 5, 6, 10, 107, 267)
```

Comment: And to make sure you're going to delete the ones you want to:  `Select  * from myTable where  group_id = 5
AND member_id not in ( 5, 6, 10, 107, 267)`

Answer (score 0):

Best method I found is at ExpressionEngine community member Bhashkar Yadav's [Sidd3](http://www.sidd3.com/mass-delete-members-in-expressionengine/)

Comment: It would be nice if you could add a quick summary here-  you never know if a webpage will go away